# It is impossible to know how old I truly am - What am i?

Tags: riddle

I fall in flames,

I go upwards swiftly,

My origin is Buddhist in belief, but not in karma

It is impossible to know how old I truly am

What am I?

PS. First riddle

Comment: They don't know how old I am. They found armor in my belly. From the sixteenth century. Conquistador, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> a phoenix?

I fall in flames,

> Phoenix dies by burning up

I go upwards swiftly,

> It's a bird!

My origin is Buddhist in belief, but not in karma

> Something to do with the theme of rebirth? (I'm not very familiar with Buddhist beliefs, so I might be missing something more fitting here.)

It is impossible to know how old I truly am

> Phoenix dies and is reborn over and over, so it would be very hard to tell how old it actually is.

Comment: Correct! Buddhist line is Reincarnation but rebirth is close enough!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

> A meteorite

It falls from the sky in flames

Impossible to truly determine its age

Goes up swiftly in space

Comment: Not quite! Meteorites aren't buddhist :P